# Git незакомиченные изменения

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote

Как быть, если работал дома, но класс не дописал, хочу дописать на работе, а после сделать коммит.

Как отправить незакомиченные данные в удаленный реп?

Comment: Вы либо делаете коммит, либо нет. Можно послать файл по электронной почте, но зачем тогда вообще гит?  
Обычно для таких вещей просто создается ветка, в которой происходит что угодно на свете, а когда ситуация стабилизируется, ветка мерджится с основной веткой разработки.

Comment: в git принято делать "мелкие коммиты". И такой проблемы не возникнет. Создали скелет будущего класса - закоммитили, написали метод - коммит. Это на первый взгляд выглядит глупо, но потом придет осознание. Лишний коммит всегда можно удалить, а судорожно жать Ctrl+Z и думать, дойду ли до нужного места...


Но если Вам все таки хочется сделать так, как Вы хотите - сделайте ветку, закоммитье туда, пусть даже кривое и отправьте ветку на сервер. На работе сделаете мердж с нее. Или просто поработаете в ней.  А когда все сделаете - мержд.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно [сделать из этих изменений новую временную ветку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437779/181472), запушить эту ветку на remote, на работе скачать и дальше работать. Когда изменения достигнут какого-то логичного состояния, добавить их в предыдущий коммит (или если вы делали несколько коммитов в новой ветке, слить их в один) и ветку смерджить в вашу рабочую ветку. (Предполагаю, что вы не в `master` работаете).

По пунктам:

1. [Делаем новую ветку и коммитим в нее изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437779/181472)

   ```
   git add .
   git checkout -b develop-temp
   git commit -m'temporary commit'
   ```
2. Заливаем временную ветку на удаленный репозиторий. Предполагаю, что удаленный репозиторий называется `origin`, иначе замените имя на верное.

   ```
   git push -u origin develop-temp
   ```
3. Приходим на работу, забираем ветку. Можно продолжать работу.

   ```
   git checkout -b develop-temp origin/develop-temp
   ```
4. Временную ветку можно использовать дальше, чтобы снова поработать дома (хотя вообще-то это трудоголизм). Когда она не нужна, удалите её:

   ```
   git push origin :develop-temp
   ```