# Как в git выделить изменения в новую ветку?

Tags: git, git-branch

Есть репозиторий с ветками `master` и `develop`.

Работал с веткой `develop`, внес несколько изменений.

Как правильно создать новую ветку `feature` которая будет копией `develop` (с сохранением всех изменений), а `develop` привести к состоянию предыдущего коммита?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Прядок действий:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

Это оставит вашу текущую ветку в текущем состоянии, создаст и сделает активной новую ветку с сохранением всех изменений. Потом можно делать коммиты:

```
git add <files>
```

И коммитить в новую ветку:

```
git commit
```

Изменения в рабочей директории — как индексированные, так и неиндексированные — пока не принадлежат ни 1 ветке. Этими действиями вы измените ветку, в которой будут сохранены изменения.

Вы не обнуляете оригинальную ветку, она остается в прежнем состоянии. Последний коммит в  останется прежним. Вместо этого создаем новую ветку `checkout -b` и делаем коммиты уже в нее.

> Это перевод ответа @knittl [Move existing, uncommited work to a new
>   branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommited-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git)

Comment: Рад видеть переводчика вопросов по Git! Перевел что понял, с этой фразой действительно проблема. Кстати, в ЛС тут нельзя писать )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Благодарен за вашу помощь, а с ЛС я действительно "погорячился" :)

Comment: автор ответил: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommited-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git/1394804?noredirect=1#comment51223110_1394804

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно создать новую ветку feature которая будет копией develop

например, так:

```
$ git branch feature develop
```

> а develop привести к состоянию предыдущего коммита?

например, так («предыдущий» — в буквальном смысле, т.е. на один коммит «назад» по истории):

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

но тут есть «подводный» камень — если эта ветка синхронизируется ещё с каким-нибудь репозиторием, то такое удаление приведёт лишь к дальнейшим проблемам.

по-моему, лучший путь: не переписывать историю существующих веток, а просто создавать новые. например, так, как в первом примере (но с «отступом» на один коммит назад от текущего состояния ветки `develop`):

```
$ git branch newdevelop develop^
```

Comment: @NickVolynkin, возможно, но вряд ли. потому что заключительная фраза вопроса с такой поправкой: *develop привести к состоянию последнего коммита в develop* — звучит, по-моему, ещё более загадочно.

Answer (score 2):

> а develop привести к состоянию предыдущего коммита?

Насколько я понимаю, под «предыдущим» здесь понимается последний, т.е. `HEAD`, а не `HEAD^`.

Оба предлагаемых способа приводят к тому, что ветка `develop` остается нетронутой, а «хвост изменений» исчезает из нее, становясь новым коммитом в `new_branch`. Когда вы переключитесь обратно на `develop`, рабочая область снова будет чистой (т.е. соответстовать `HEAD`).

#### Через `checkout -b`

Это несколько необычно, но я предлагаю индексировать файлы сразу. Если вы случайно сбросите изменения в рабочей области, то сможете восстановить их из индекса. Даже если будет сброшен индекс **и** рабочая область, то изменения все равно [можно почти полностью восстановить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424384/181472).

Итак:

1. [Индексируем всю рабочую область](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431840/181472)

   ```
   git add .
   ```
2. Создаем ветку

   ```
   git checkout -b new_branch
   ```
3. Делаем коммит, если хотим. Можно продолжить работу и сделать коммит позже.

   ```
   git commit -m'commit message'
   ```

#### Через `stash branch`

Можно сохранить изменения в stash, а потом создать из них новую ветку. Каждое сохрание в stash по своей структуре — это такой же коммит. Просто он хранится особым образом.

1. Сохраняем в stash текущие изменения

   ```
   git stash save --all
   ```
2. Делаем новую ветку на основе только что сохраненного stash (при этом сохраненный stash остается в начале стека). Последним коммитом этой ветки будет тот, который был последним, когда создавался stash (в нашем случае это и есть последний коммит копируемой ветки).
   В результате этой команды у нас есть новая ветка, мы в нее переключились, а в рабочей области — содержимое последней записи в stash.

   ```
   git stash branch new_branch
   ```
3. Теперь можно индексировать изменения и создавать коммит. Как и в прошлом случае, это можно сделать сразу или потом.

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m'commit message'
   ```

Comment: А если в старую ветку уже сделан коммит, можно так начать новую ветку, чтобы этот коммит оказался в ней вместо старой?

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo начните новую ветку от этого коммита, а старую подвиньте на один назад. Как подвинуть: пункт 4.3 в этом ответе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472