# Как в git создать новую ветку и продолжить в ней работать с текущего момента?

Tags: git, git-branch

Я работаю в основной ветке master. С момента последнего commita есть изменения. Я не хочу комитить текущие изменения в текущую ветку. Но и терять их не хочу. Я хочу создать новую ветку, скажем test, и продолжить работать в новой ветке с текущего момента, не теряя никаких изменений. С таким расчетом, что когда я закончу в тестовой ветке, то вернусь обратно в основную (master) и солью изменения.

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Отметил дублем к  вопросу, который на мой взгляд абсолютно о том же. Если я все-таки ошибся, сообщите, переоткрою. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437779/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Берёте...

#### ...и делаете!

Git не даст вам просто так потерять внесённые поверх коммита изменения, поэтому можете смело делать новую ветку:

```
git checkout -b test
```

Опасаться этого стоило бы, переключаясь на другую ветку, которая находится на другом коммите (скажем, при `git checkout dev`); Git бы одёрнул вас вот таким сообщением:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        файл1
        папка/файл2
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

#### Запасной план

Есть `stash`, в котором можно разместить изменения, которые не хочется коммитить, но хочется сохранить на некоторое время. В данном случае применение стэша совершенно излишне, но может пригодиться, к примеру, когда изменения были применены не в той ветке:

```
git stash -u     # с сохранением untracked (неотслеживаемых) файлов
git checkout dev # меняем ветку на другую, скажем, уже существующую
git stash pop    # забираем изменения обратно и выкидываем из стэша
                 # ^- этот прямоугольник получился случайно, честно
```

Изменения из стэша вполне могут конфликтовать с состоянием другой ветки, и если так выйдет, возникнет конфликт и набор изменений останется в стэше (потому что "чисто" применить их не получилось).

Stash один для всего репозитория и специфичен для отдельной локальной копии: условно говоря, он **лично ваш**.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас все изменения в master закоммичены, то вы можете смело создавать новую ветку. В нее войдут только те изменения, которые есть в remote мастера. Когда вы вернетесь обратно в master, закомиченные изменения останутся на месте (поскольку были сохранены в local). Главное не забудьте сделать pull, если содержимое ветки test уже вольете в мастер.

Comment: Я не хочу комитить текущие изменения в текущую ветку (master).

Comment: @MikhailDanshin и в чем причина? При коммите изменения сохраняются только локально и не попадают в ремоут.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ
`git checkout -b %branch_name%`

Comment: Почему `checkout`? У него же незакоммиченные изменения.

Comment: Изменениям оно не помешает

Comment: @Qwertiy,
`Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the <branch>.`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

При этом есть возможность сразу создать ветвь из текущей

Comment: Да, всё верно. Перепутал.