# Как создать новую ветку и залить изменения

Tags: git

Я клонировал удаленный репозиторий  с проектом с ветки master, сделал несколько изменений, теперь мне нужно создать отдельную ветку перенести в нее изменения, отправить эти изменения в удаленный репозиторий.  Как это можно сделать?

p.s. меня бросили на проект с git, но я с ним никогда не работал.

Comment: На второй вопрос ответ здесь: [Как отправить изменения из текущей ветки в новую ветку в удалённом репозитории?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543752/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Вот тут тоже есть ответ на первый вопрос: [Как в git создать новую ветку и продолжить в ней работать с текущего момента?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494215/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-git-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Если информации по ссылкам вам недостаточно, то уточняйте подробности или вопросы задавайте )

Answer (score 11):

Если вы еще не коммитили изменения, тогда создайте новую ветку `branch_name`

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

Индексируйте ваши изменения

```
git add .
```

Создайте коммит

```
git commit -m 'Комментарий к ветке branch_name'
```

И отправьте изменения на удаленный сервер

```
git push origin branch_name
```